# Find and arrange words with same letters from list

Tags: dictionary, ms-word

I am making a word game and I am wondering how to find and arrange words in a list that have the same letters. In my game, you are presented with 5 letters, and you then have to rearrange the letters tp make a word. So the word could be "acorn", but those 5 letters could also make up "narco" or  "racon" which are words in my .txt dictionary (shown on the left).

Example, third line on the right:

[image]

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: olly_uk: The list will be made into a .CSV table file for use with GameSalad.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical anagram problem, You can store the words as Hashmap key-ed on the sorted version of the word, so a list like

```
  clay, lacy, note, tern, tone, nest, sent
```

would be stored as hashmap of

```
   acly => {clay , lacy}
   enot => {tone, note}
   enst => {sent, nest}
   enrt => {tern}
```

Easy to build this, sudo algorithm is

```
  Hashmap<String, HashSet<String>> h;
  foreach word in list
      String sorted = sort(word); \\so if word is sent, sorted is enst
      HashSet<String> currentSet = h.get(sorted);
      currentSet.add(word);
```

Comment: Many thanks Adithya! That looks like what I was after indeed.

I'm a bit of a noob, how would I execute this in a unix terminal? (I have a .txt that I want to use as my input)